# MS Word replace/remove multiple lines starting with same pattern

Tags: microsoft-word

Here is an example:

> 6374-6375 | Added on Wednesday, February 18, 2015 9:18:24
>
> Each teacher had thousands of students, and they would regularly challenge the students of the other teachers.
>
> 6376-6376 | Added on Wednesday, February 18, 2015 9:18:50
>
> As the Lord was young and restless, He would also quarrel with the other students.
>
> 6378-6379 | Added on Wednesday, February 18, 2015 9:19:23
>
> Someone would challenge, “Your teacher is not very learned.” Another would say, “See whose disciple I am.”

As you can see, before each paragraph there is a line starting with the same pattern. I need to get rid of all those lines in document so that I get this:

> Each teacher had thousands of students, and they would regularly challenge the students of the other teachers.
>
> As the Lord was young and restless, He would also quarrel with the other students.
>
> Someone would challenge, “Your teacher is not very learned.” Another would say, “See whose disciple I am.”

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula

```
????-???? | Added on*:*:???
```

in search and replace dialog’s search field. Also, *Use wildcards* option has to be selected for this to work.

[image]